# await with null propagation System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, exception, async-await, nullreferenceexception, null-propagation-operator

I have the following code:

```
await _user?.DisposeAsync();
```

`Visual Studio` highlights this code, saying 'Possible NullReferenceException'

by the way, without `await` `Visual Studio` doesn't show this warning
Why `NullReferenceException` is possible here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`await null` will throw a `NullReferenceException`. Therefore if `_user` is null, then `_user?.DisposeAsync()` will return `null`, and the `await` will throw.

You can do:

```
if (_user != null)
{
    await _user.DisposeAsync();
}
```

(you might need a local copy of `_user` if it might change between reads)

or:

```
await (_user?.DisposeAsync() ?? ValueTask.CompletedTask);
```

(Prior to .NET 5, you will need:)

```
await (_user?.DisposeAsync().AsTask() ?? Task.CompletedTask);
```

Comment: Didn't figure out the .AsTask() extension, but this works:
`await (_user?.DisposeAsync() ?? Task.CompletedTask);`

Comment: @jornhd [`DisposeAsync` returns a `ValueTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iasyncdisposable.disposeasync?view=net-6.0). You can't apply `??` between a `ValueTask?` and a `Task`, [see here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUKgBgAJVMBWAbjz1QA4SA2IgMQHtWAKASQEEBnAJ5QAxgBEAlnwAOrPgEMARgBsApkWAALcVADmASjwBvPEVOnUATiIdN2nQH4AdBOmyV/IcI56i9+40cAYVYAWylVYBU4VAY9CiI8AF8gA=). It looks like your `DisposeAsync()` method returns a `Task` and not a `ValueTask`? So it doesn't come from `IAsyncDisposable`

Answer (score 4):

Async methods return a `Task` that can be awaited.  If `_user` is null then you would not be returning a `Task` but null instead

Answer (score 2):

await is expecting a result. If _user is null then the result will be null, hence the NullReferenceException.